# Connecting mongodb database with django project

Tags: django, database, mongodb, web, djongo

I want to connect my database on Atlas(Mlab) with my django project. I have python 3.7, django,djongo installed successfully. I am facing an error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

I am sharing my settings.py (database section) file for your reference:

```
DATABASES = {  
        'default': {  
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'ReminderSystemDbTest',
            'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://jigarjoshiuser:joshipinakin@cluster0.mhzxu.gcp.mongodb.net/ReminderSystemDbTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'USER': 'jigarjoshiuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'joshipinakin',
        }   
        #mongodb+srv://jigarjoshiuser:joshipinakin@databaseconnectivtiy.mhzxu.gcp.mongodb.net/ReminderSystemDbTest?retryWrites=true&w=majority
    }  
}
```

I am sharing my manage.py file for reference :

```
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'db_connectivity.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my wsgi file is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys

sys.path.append("F:/connecting_database/db_connectivity")
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'db_connectivity.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Hierarchy is :

```
CONNECTING_DATABASE->
   db_connectivity
   db_connectivity
       pycache
       __init.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
       db.sqlite3
   manage.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You're required to update Django database configuration in settings.py but there's more to it.

Mongo requires a little more to work with Django however the 2 are a great fit

In databases config for default db, update to include the Mongo new backend which at the moment is going to be facilitated by a plug in. That is the only way to translate the orm into Mongo compatible dB syntax and use Django tools like orm

Try django-mongodb-engine.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Please share the suggested code or explain it in a deeper way. Thank you for your support.